# Android Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000050 (code=1) will trying to load an activity

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine

i am trying to load an android activity from unity, i made all the steps from the tutorials as it supposed to by, 
when i am clicking the button to open the android activity i get this err:

"Android Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000050 (code=1)"
will trying to load an activity

any suggestions?
thank you

Comment: perhaps click Edit, add your code where you call to load the activity

Comment: @Joe the err append on physical devices only, when i am trying from android emulator the activity is working. i have no idea why